# Unity - post processing results in split screen in VR?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, virtual-reality

Ok, I'm building for Oculus rift and am just trying to get chromatic aberration, or really any post-processing effects to work. The only way the effects show up is if I apply them to my CenterEyeAnchor camera in the OVRCameraRig. This works in editor but when I plug a headset in, the screen gets split into 2 x the number of effects scripts I apply:

[image]

I've been trying legacy image effects scripts (the up to date one does nothing), as well as this downloaded shader for chromatic aberration:

```
Shader "Hidden/LensCAAndDistortion" {
                Properties {
                                _MainTex ("RGB", 2D) = "" {}
                                _BorderTex ("Border", 2D) = "" {}
                }

                CGINCLUDE

                #include "UnityCG.cginc"




                uniform float _RedCyan;
                uniform float _GreenMagenta;
                uniform float _BlueYellow;
                uniform float _Zoom;
                uniform float _BarrelDistortion;
                uniform int _BorderOnOff;

                sampler2D _BorderTex;
                sampler2D _MainTex;


                half4 _MainTex_TexelSize;
                half4 _UV_Transform = half4(1, 0, 0, 1);



                float2 barrelDistortion(float2 theUV)
                {

                float2 h = theUV.xy - 0.5;
                float r2 = h.x * h.x + h.y * h.y;
                float f = 1 + r2 * (_BarrelDistortion * sqrt(r2));

                return f * (1.0+_Zoom) * h + 0.5;

                }

                half4 fragLens (v2f_img i) : SV_Target {

                                                                half2 zoomUV = i.uv;
                                                                float4 theScreen = tex2D(_MainTex, zoomUV);

                                                                if ((_RedCyan == 0) && (_GreenMagenta == 0) && (_BlueYellow == 0))
                                                                {
                                                                                zoomUV = barrelDistortion(zoomUV);
                                                                                if (_BorderOnOff == 1)
                                                                                {
                                                                                                theScreen.r = tex2D(_MainTex, zoomUV).r * tex2D(_BorderTex, ((zoomUV * 0.9375) + 0.03125)).r;
                                                                                                theScreen.g = tex2D(_MainTex, zoomUV).g * tex2D(_BorderTex, ((zoomUV * 0.9375) + 0.03125)).g;
                                                                                                theScreen.b = tex2D(_MainTex, zoomUV).b * tex2D(_BorderTex, ((zoomUV * 0.9375) + 0.03125)).b;
                                                                                }
                                                                                if (_BorderOnOff == 0)
                                                                                {                                              
                                                                                                theScreen.r = tex2D(_MainTex, zoomUV).r;
                                                                                                theScreen.g = tex2D(_MainTex, zoomUV).g;
                                                                                                theScreen.b = tex2D(_MainTex, zoomUV).b;
                                                                                }
                                                                }

                                                                if ((_RedCyan != 0) || (_GreenMagenta != 0) || (_BlueYellow != 0))
                                                                {              
                                                                                half2 redUV;
                                                                                half2 greUV;
                                                                                half2 bluUV;

                                                                                float redcyan = _RedCyan*0.001;
                                                                                float gremag = _GreenMagenta*0.001;
                                                                                float bluyel = _BlueYellow*0.001;

                                                                                zoomUV = barrelDistortion(zoomUV);
                                                                                redUV = (zoomUV * (1.0+redcyan)) - (redcyan/2.0);
                                                                                greUV = (zoomUV * (1.0+gremag)) - (gremag/2.0);
                                                                                bluUV = (zoomUV * (1.0+bluyel)) - (bluyel/2.0);

                                                                                if (_BorderOnOff == 1)
                                                                                {
                                                                                theScreen.r = tex2D(_MainTex, redUV).r * tex2D(_BorderTex, ((redUV * 0.9375) + 0.03125)).r;
                                                                                theScreen.g = tex2D(_MainTex, greUV).g * tex2D(_BorderTex, ((greUV * 0.9375) + 0.03125)).g;
                                                                                theScreen.b = tex2D(_MainTex, bluUV).b * tex2D(_BorderTex, ((bluUV * 0.9375) + 0.03125)).b;
                                                                                }
                                                                                if (_BorderOnOff == 0)
                                                                                {                                              
                                                                                theScreen.r = tex2D(_MainTex, redUV).r;
                                                                                theScreen.g = tex2D(_MainTex, greUV).g;
                                                                                theScreen.b = tex2D(_MainTex, bluUV).b;
                                                                                }
                                                                }
                                                                return theScreen;
                }              




                ENDCG 

Subshader {
                  ZTest Always Cull Off ZWrite Off
      ColorMask RGB             


Pass {    

      CGPROGRAM
      #pragma vertex vert_img
      #pragma fragment fragLens
      ENDCG
  }  


}

Fallback off

} // shader
```

What is happening here? Can it be fixed?

Script:

```
void Start () 
    {
        if(!SystemInfo.supportsImageEffects)
        {
            enabled = false;
            return;
        }
    }

    void OnRenderImage (RenderTexture sourceTexture, RenderTexture destTexture) 
    {
        if(LensShader != null)
        {
            material.SetFloat("_RedCyan", RedCyan * 10.0f); 
            material.SetFloat("_GreenMagenta", GreenMagenta * 10.0f);
            material.SetFloat("_BlueYellow", BlueYellow * 10.0f);
            material.SetFloat("_Zoom", 0.0f - Zoom);
            material.SetFloat("_BarrelDistortion", BarrelDistortion);
            material.SetTexture ("_BorderTex", TrimTexture);

            if (TrimExtents == true)
            {
                material.SetInt("_BorderOnOff", 1);
            }
            else
            {
                material.SetInt("_BorderOnOff", 0);
            }

            Graphics.Blit(sourceTexture, destTexture, material); 
        }
        else
        {
            Graphics.Blit(sourceTexture, destTexture);
        }


    }


    void Update () 
    {

    }


    void OnDisable ()
    {
        if(curMaterial)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(curMaterial);
        }
```

Comment: Please post your script.

Comment: see my edit above